# Hartl tutorial ch 8.2.4: Test errors when using fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, railstutorial.org

The login test

```
$ bundle exec rake test TEST=test/integration/users_login_test.rb \
>                       TESTOPTS="--name test_login_with_valid_information"
```

should pass, but I get the error message: "ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:" 3 times. A number of other similar posts have been answered with the advice to check the .yml file as it needs to see spaces, not tabs. I tried pasting directly into the file from the tutorial, and have tried all sorts of combinations of tabs and spaces, but cannot get rid of this error. Here is my /test/fixtures/users.yml file:

```
#michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Here is my /test/integration/users_login_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  end

end
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, things have been going so well, it's frustating to grind to a halt!

Comment: The first line of your YAML is commented out (`#`), which seems like a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan. It's amazing how many times you can look at something right in front of you, but still not see.

Answer (score 0):

In your **test/fixtures/users.yml** file:

> ```
> #michael:
>   name: Michael Example
>   email: michael@example.com
>   password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
> ```

there is an unnecessary `#` (comments) in front of `michael`.

[reference: Rails Tutorial [repo](https://bitbucket.org/railstutorial/sample_app_4th_ed/src/2e80e463c7900e329555116119060f2a05f693cd/test/fixtures/users.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)]